Comparison of Strength of Hydrogen Bonds of Sulphur and Chlorine
In my textbook, the order for strength of H-bonding is given as
$$\ce{F > O > N > S > Cl}$$
I wonder how Cl has less strength of H-bonding than sulphur despite chlorine being more electronegative and smaller in size?

If the order here is correct, I guess it is because Sulphur is a better electron donor than chlorine. For H bonding, there should be a electronegative group connected to H, so that H has a partial positive charge. Chlorine does this as it is more electronegative. But for H-bonding you also need an electron donating element to put electron in Antibonding molecular orbital of H-X bond(note that there is no 100% covalent bond. H-bonds are weaker than normal covalent bonds), which forms the H-bond. Although, I think Chlorine is better at H bonding, but it may vary with different compounds.

Yeah, that makes sense but can you elaborate like when S will do better H-bonding than Cl and vice-vera? Also as you said why will it vary with different compounds?

I am not so sure about this, You should ask a more qualified person, like your teacher. Generally, if the electron pulling atom is the same, then the better the electron donating element, better the H-bond. For example: HF-HF hydrogen bond is weaker than HF-NH3 hydrogen bond, as N donates lone pair better. If the electron pulling and lone pair donating element is same, then Cl dominates due to high electronegativity, HCl has much stronger H-bonds in comparison to H2S

Perhaps worth including which textbook this is.

@BuckThorn It is Cengage Inorganic Chemistry for JEE mains and advanced by KS Verma
